# Search functionality in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list-view and applying search functionality on it, using following:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // When user changed the Text
      LabelUser.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("count"+s);
}});
```

After entering the the characters  in edit-text the index of the temporary list view changes and i am getting wrong record using following:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectedFromList = (list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    Constants.LABELID = labelIdArray[(int) id];  
    System.out.println("id.LABELID"+id); 
    System.out.println("id.selectedFromList"+selectedFromList);
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mysampleapp.DASHBOARDTAB"));
}});
```

I  want to get temporary list view after applying the search so that i can get the correct index from original list-view or can any one suggest me how to get the string from the list view selected after filtering the list view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the arraylist or array to your listview adapter, then you can check the arraylist or array, if your word is there in it. then call `listview.setSelection(your_arraylist_current_position);`

```
for(int i=0;i<arralist.size();i++)
{
    if(arraylist.get(i).startwith(searchingword))
      {
        listview.setSelection(i);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its a custom listview having a TextView in each row, then you can get the string of the selected list item like this in listView.onItemClick where v is the View

```
TextView Selecteditem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listitem);
String mText = Selecteditem.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well! I have done the same thing but in a different way than yours.

Following are the broad level steps:
 - When the text in the EditText changes, you can search the list and create a temporary List(ArrayList) containing the search items.
 - Then Set the ListView adapter to the temporary list by calling              `listView.setAdapter(temporaryList);`
 - Also, define a flag for eg isSearchOn. When The content in EditText changes, and its not "", make isSearchOn = true and false otherwise.
 - On the other hand, in onItemClick,

```
if(isSearchOn)
   {
      //search temporaryList
   }
   else
   {
      //search originalList
   }
```

This way, you will always get the correct item. Hope this helps.